# Entity Framework: Add child record to and existing parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to add a child record to and existing parent.

I call the following methods

```
_handler.Update(custOrder);
_handler.Save();


public TEntity Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            Entities.Attach(entity);
            DataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return entity;
        }
```

and

```
  public void Save() {
            try
            {
                base.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
```

The custOrder contains the parent (which already exists) and a new child record that needs to be added. E.g. Adding an order item for an existing order.

However when I execute this the child does not get added.

I am not sure how specify that the parent has not changed but a child was added

Please advice.

Comment: Are you executing your `Update` and your `Save` on the same context?

Comment: yes I use the save for saving multiple transactions, it works fine when I add a new Order with items

Comment: That's not what I meant. The `DataContext` that you're using in the `Update` method: Is that the same context that gets `Save` run on it?

Comment: What I am not sure is how specify that the parent has not changed but a child was added

Comment: Yes, its the same context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got the answer it was a bit subtle have to admit, The parent entity needed to be added instead of attached and the state set to modified afterwards.

```
 public TEntity Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            Entities.Add(entity);
            DataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return entity;
        }
```

Comment: Great answer!  Why did somebody downvote it?  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell EF that the child itself was actually added. It won't assume from the parent that something needs to be added when the EntityState is set to Modified. You need to Add that new child record to the context, and then run the save.

Assuming `OrderItem` class as your child:

```
dbContext.OrderItems.Add(myNewOrderItem);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Can I do that using these methods (modifying the Update method) or else what do I need to introduce.

Comment: Can I do it in a generic way so that it can handle any kind of parent child object?

Comment: You should be able to, but unless I know more about how you're currently doing your other ones I don't know how to help you out with that.